# How to render from a mdx file of same directory to a react component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby, tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { Wrapper, SectionTitle, Header, SectionSubTitle, SEO } from 'components'
import { Layout } from 'layouts'
import { Content } from 'layouts/components'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import config from 'config/siteConfig'
import Data from 'models/Data'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import * as everything from './about.mdx'

import { FeaturedPosts } from 'components/FeaturedPost'

interface Props {
  data: Data
}

const HomePage = (props: Props) => {
  // console.log()
  const { edges } = props.data.allMdx

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Helmet title={`Blog | ${config.siteTitle}`} />
      <SEO path="/" data={{ title: config.siteTitleAlt }} />
      <Header>
        <SectionTitle>
          {config.siteTitle}
          <Line />
          <SectionSubTitle>{config.siteDescription}</SectionSubTitle>
        </SectionTitle>
      </Header>
      <Wrapper>

        <MDXContent>

        </MDXContent>

      </Wrapper>
    </Layout>
  )
}
// Gatsby needs this default export to work.
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-default-export
export default HomePage

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allMdx(
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date, frontmatter___title], order: DESC }
      limit: 10
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            path
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            date(formatString: "MMMM D, YYYY")
            standardDate: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
          excerpt(pruneLength: 200)
          timeToRead
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const Line = styled.hr`
  color: white;
  width: 5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  height: 3px;
`

const Title = styled.span`
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
`

const DateTag = styled.time`
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
`
```

I am new to web dev and react, mdx, graphql, tsx, gatsby.
Here is my index.tsx
and I also have about.mdx file in the same directory which renders inside /about path.
What I want to do is render the same content from about.mdx to my index.tsx file.
But I'm not sure how and where to put it and import it to my index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can create another GraphQL query to fetch the `about.mdx` content in your `index.tsx`:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allMdx(
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date, frontmatter___title], order: DESC }
      limit: 10
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            path
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            date(formatString: "MMMM D, YYYY")
            standardDate: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
          excerpt(pruneLength: 200)
          timeToRead
        }
      }
    }
    aboutContent: allMdx(
      filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {eq: "/about.mdx"  }}) {
        edges{
         node {
          fields {
            path
          }
          frontmatter {
           #your content  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Double-check the query in the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) in order to know the exact `fileAbsolutePath` or to find another suitable filter like `relativePath`, the query structure and response.

Once you validate the query, since it's aliased with `aboutContent: allMdx`, your about content will be inside:

```
  const { edges } = props.data.aboutContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the MDX file into your page and render it as a React component:

```
// Rest of imports...

import AboutMDX from './about.mdx'

const Page = () => (
  <main>
    <AboutMDX />
  </main>
)

export default Page
```